# Passing data to an onclick event is decapitalizing the string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider this fiddle:

```js
var test = $('#test');
var click = $('#click');
var data = [{
  id: "gDDWdwewqeWEDQWE222wedEDDEW"
}, {
  id: "232exEWXDWE23e21EDXXE!!@q"
}];

click.click(function() {
  var data = [{
    id: "gDDWdwewqeWEDQWE222wedEDDEW"
  }, {
    id: "232exEWXDWE23e21EDXXE!!@q"
  }];
  var html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var id = data[i].id;
    html += `<li id="${id}" onclick="anyFunction("${id}")">${id}</li>`
  }
  test.html(html);
  console.log(test.html());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="test"></ul>
<button id="click">Click me</button>
```

Click on "Click me", then right-click on the ID and inspect it, you will see the expected ID outside onclick event while an unexpected one(decapitalized) inside it, there's also space right before the passed id inside onclick event. Check the pic below.

[image]

Any idea on why this behavior is occurring? Is it a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Remove the quotes around the ${id}

Comment: Just look at your HTML string. You're basicly writing `onclick="anyFunction("`. You're closing the attribute value before you even get to the point where you're adding the ID to it.

Comment: anyFunction is a function, you need to put quotes around the string parameter so it executes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's getting translated to lower case because your HTML string is not properly escaped - jQuery's `html()` will turn attribute and element names to lowercase:

```js
$('body').html('<FOO BAR="BAZ"></FOO>');
console.log($('body').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To fix it, turn `anyFunction`'s string parameters into single-quotes rather than double-quotes:

```js
var test = $('#test');
var click = $('#click');
var data = [{
  id: "gDDWdwewqeWEDQWE222wedEDDEW"
}, {
  id: "232exEWXDWE23e21EDXXE!!@q"
}];

click.click(function() {
  var data = [{
    id: "gDDWdwewqeWEDQWE222wedEDDEW"
  }, {
    id: "232exEWXDWE23e21EDXXE!!@q"
  }];
  var html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var id = data[i].id;
    html += `<li id="${id}" onclick="anyFunction('${id}')">${id}</li>`
  }
  test.html(html);
  console.log(test.html());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="test"></ul>
<button id="click">Click me</button>
```

But inline handlers are terrible practice - it would be far better to attach the listeners properly using Javascript instead, which is not only better design-wise, but it'll also keep you from having to worry about escaping strings like that:

```js
var test = $('#test');
var click = $('#click');
var data = [{
  id: "gDDWdwewqeWEDQWE222wedEDDEW"
}, {
  id: "232exEWXDWE23e21EDXXE!!@q"
}];

click.click(function() {
  var data = [{
    id: "gDDWdwewqeWEDQWE222wedEDDEW"
  }, {
    id: "232exEWXDWE23e21EDXXE!!@q"
  }];
  var html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const id = data[i].id;
    const li = $(`<li id="${id}">${id}</li>`);
    li.on('click', () => anyFunction(id));
    test.append(li);
  }
  console.log(test.html());
})
function anyFunction(arg) {
  console.log(arg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="test"></ul>
<button id="click">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Single quotes worked, thank you! This is just an example snippet I created for an explanation.